# Does using projection makes the entity managed? - hibernate/jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My question is that: when I use projection with criteria API, does this cause the entity subject to the query managed by persistence context, thus not allowing two entities with the same Id to exist in the context?
My scenario is as follows :

1- I have an entity with a new state that I need to update

2- I need to check a subset of the old state of the entity that is already persisted because, at certain condition ( the difference between old and new data), I need to take an action (send an email)

So do I need to evict the new entity in order to get the state of the old one given that I will get it using Criteria+projection?

Comment: If you use a projection, then by definition you're not getting the entity. But why don't you just load the entity, compare its state with the new state you want to persist, and then update the entity? And why don't you post code instead of describing it?

Comment: Thanks a lot ... So you mean to compare the entities before adding the new to the context, right ?... Actually the question is more of a conceptual, that's why I didn't post the code